# Order by COLUMN which has a VARCHAR2 data type

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have a table which users can add and edit existing records. When a user enters a new record, the revision is set to '-' since it is an intial draft. When a user edits a record and its a '-' it will set the revision to 1. After that if its edited again it does revision + 1 which would be 2. And so on..

I display the history of a record in an Apex report which is sorted by revision. This worked until i reached version 10, because i now get the following:

9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
10
1
'-'

10 should follow on from 9 however it is between 2 and 1. This is because my data type is set to VARCHAR2 rather than NUMBER. Is it possible to order it correctly like so:

10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
'-'

Note: Revision may grow and grow, could even reach 100. The easiest method would be to change the data type to NUMBER and using 0 instead of '-'. However, I'd prefer a dash if i could.

Thank you.

Comment: Do **not** store numbers in varchar columns. Instead of using '-' as the value for "initial" you could use `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend converting it to a number and using zero or null instead of `'-'`. 
A numeric column would also be helpful for things like comparing which version is later or finding adjacent versions:

```
select...
    where version_a > version_b

select...
    where version_a = version_b + 1
```

If you have a `varchar` field, special logic will be needed for anything like that.  In my opinion, if you want to display `-` for zero, you can handle that easily in the display logic rather than putting it in the database.

However, if you really need to keep it a character, you should be able to do something like this:

```
order by case when column = '-' then 0 else to_number(column) end descending
```

You need to check for `'-'` as a special case, because converting that to a number will fail.

Comment: when i try converting the character i get the following error: ORA-01722: invalid number. Is it correct? to me it reads if you find a '-' in column, then display 0, else display the number as normal, should it not be the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

Use a numeric type, then for display purposes you can wrap the return value for that field with a
 `CASE WHEN field=0 THEN '-' ELSE field-converted-to-string END as revisionStr`
(use appropriate function for field-converted-to-string!)

Sorting on 'field' will work (DESC) automatically for you, as it's just a normal number.

**EDIT**
example :

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN revision=0 THEN
    '-' 
  ELSE
    RTrim(CAST(revision AS varchar(30))) 
  END AS revisionStr
FROM table
ORDER by revision DESC
```

Comment: Please could you provide an example? I have changed my column to Number, and now trying to complete the following you have recommended.